# building maven project when adding dependency on parent jar

Tags: java, maven

Hi guys wondering if you can let me know where I am going wrong.

In my **pom.xml** I added a dependency for *org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:jar:1.5.4*
via the following:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now during a build I get the error "Could not resolve dependencies for project com.law:test_pro:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:jar:1.5.4"

In my local repository I have all jars for containing sub-projects but no jar for the parent jar which the build process seems to be looking for.

Comment: What files currently reside under <local_m2_repo_dir>/org/powermock/powermock-mockito-release-full/1.5.4?

Comment: Could you post your complete POM?

Comment: @JamesB there are no jars for some reason. just the following files

_remote.repositories  
powermock-mockito-release-full-1.5.4.jar.lastUpdated   
powermock-mockito-release-full-1.5.4.pom   
powermock-mockito-release-full-1.5.4.pom.sha1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a parent pom file available for the Maven co-ordinate

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Hence, you need to add the type 'pom' to this like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i tried that previously. it still builds all the jars for the sub artifacts except for the parent artifact: powermock-mockito-release-full-1.5.4

Comment: OK, let me add this dependency to dummy project here.

Comment: @L-Samuels It did, see my answer though. You need to add the type element with the value pom to your POM file.

Comment: thanks its seems the ide was slow to reflect it worked.